# Как поставить тригер на последнюю ветку в TeamCity?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, git, teamcity

У меня в приложении есть ветки `release/{version}`

Например:

```
release/1.0
release/2.0
release/3.1
```

Я могу задать в TeamCity отслеживание веток с помощью определённого синтаксиса, но в документации описано только использование `*`

`+:/refs/heads/release/*` отслеживает все релизные ветки, но как мне поставить тригер только на последнюю (`release/3.1`)?
Я пробовал подставлять различные regex выражения, TeamCity либо начинал отслеживать все ветки сразу, либо просто не видел ничего.

Answer (score 1):

Одно из простых решений - [Trigger rules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/configuring-vcs-triggers.html)

Configuring the project -> Triggers -> VCS Triggers -> VCS Trigger Rules -> add new rule

Например, запускать сборку только если в комментарии к коммиту в ветке release/x.x содержится ключевое слово. Либо сделать наоборот - не запускать сборку со стоп-словом. Решать вам.